# Android emulator crashes while running libgdx app

Tags: android

Adding folders armeabi and armeabi-v7a into android projects /libs folder also not working.

Thanks

Comment: logcat please. code snippet please

Comment: *gets out crystal ball*... nope, the spirits aren't talking today.  We're not mind-readers or mediums.  Give us some information to work with.

Comment: Now it's just showing me a black window with following message:                                                          04-07 13:32:56.101: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 0

Comment: Be sure to have your emulator enabled in hosted gpu mood instead of snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded latest libgdx and it worked fine on my android emulator now.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Use host GPU" on creating a new AVD.